# How to make this map function not repeat itself?

Tags: reactjs

I have the following code:

```
    const dataService = serviceItems.map((serviceItems) => [{
      text: 'Data of Service',
      ul: [`A: ${service.serviceCategoryName}
            B: ${translateUserRules(service.departmentAssessment)}
            C: ${servicePaymentMethod(service.paymentMethod)}
            D: ${getContractName(service.contractId)}
            E: ${getProjectName(service.projectId)}\n\n`
      ]


    }];
```

I tried to do it this way but I get the following error:

```
    const filtered = dataService.filter(x => !x.includes(dataService))
```

Argument of type 'string' is not assignable to parameter of type '{ text: string; ul: string[]; }'.

And I would like that after the map takes a turn it doesn't happen again. How can I do this?

Comment: `dataService` is an array of object. Therefore you are calling `.includes` on an object, which is invalid. What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: _And I would like that after the map takes a turn it doesn't happen again. How can I do this?_ What does this mean? Do you want to take only the first element of the array?

Comment: I'm creating a pdf that takes this information from the database. But every time I register a new service, a new list appears. And I wish only the first list would appear

Comment: If you can clarify your end goal - in a simple, reproducible way - I would love to help you. But I personally don't understand the problem here. What do you want to filter out? Why are you mapping over the `serviceItems`?

Comment: @SinanYaman So, when I click on my button to generate the PDF, I have 2 pieces of information, for example, in the table. Only I would like only the first information to appear. The serviceItems is the variable that I'm traversing to get the information contained in the table

Comment: I genuinely don't want to know about the context of your app, can you summarize me `javascript` wise (e.g. I want to get the first element of `serviceItems` then filter it out based on condition X)

Comment: @SinanYaman I don't want my object list to repeat. Only that